# Share variables between 2 pages in dash application

Tags: python, plotly-dash

This code located in pg2.py

```
def parse_contents_1(contents, filename, date, n_clicks_b):
    global nfile
    content_type, content_string = contents.split(',')
    decoded = base64.b64decode(content_string)
    try:
        if 'csv' in filename:
            # Assume that the user uploaded a CSV file
            df = pd.read_csv(
                io.StringIO(decoded.decode('utf-8')), skiprows=7)
            nfile[filename] = df.to_dict('records')
        elif 'xls' in filename:
            # Assume that the user uploaded an excel file
            df = pd.read_excel(io.BytesIO(decoded), skiprows=7)
            nfiles[filename] = df.to_dict('records')
        # return nfile
    except Exception as e:
        print(e)
        return html.Div([
            'Yüklədiyiniz fayl formatı dəstəklənmir.'
        ])
    fName = filename.split('_')[0] + ' ' + filename.split('_')[1]
    return dbc.Col([html.Div([
        html.H5(children = [fName], id= {"type":"dynamic-name", "index": n_clicks_b }), dcc.Slider(id={"type":"id_1", "index": n_clicks_b },step=1)])], width = 5)




@callback([Output('output-dataBS', 'children'),
               Output('store-data-BS', 'data')],
              [Input('upload-data-BS', 'contents'),
               Input("dynamic-add-filter", "n_clicks"),
               State('upload-data-BS', 'filename'),
               State('upload-data-BS', 'last_modified'),
               State("output-dataBS", "children")])
def update_output(list_of_contents, n_clicks_b, list_of_names, list_of_dates, children_bs):
    if list_of_contents is not None:
        new_children = [
            parse_contents_1(c, n, d, n_clicks_b) for c, n, d in
            zip(list_of_contents, list_of_names, list_of_dates)]
        return children_bs.append(new_children), nfiles
    raise PreventUpdate
```

But this code located in my app.py script

```
dcc.Store(id={"type":'store-data-BS', "index": pages.pg2.n_clicks_b},storage_type="session")
```

When I run my application and start to upload my data to the dcc.Store but

I get this error code:

AttributeError: module ‘pages.pg2’ has no attribute ‘n_clicks_b’

I think I can solve this error by creating class.

Please, if you have any solution for it, help me.

Thanks

Comment: Duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74233479/plotly-dash-sharing-data-between-more-than-two-pages/74248484#74248484

Comment: No it is not duplicate of my question. I want to apply Pattern-Matching Callbacks to my code

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure I understand your problém correctly. Make sure that there is the 'n_clicks_b' stated as an Input in callback of the pages.pg2,too. Otherwise it will have "no attribute ‘n_clicks_b’".